# Arduino Sublime Text 2. I can compile but can't upload. Error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, upload, arduino, sublimetext2

I have seen several questions answered about similar problems, but none that completely solved my problem.

I'm trying to upload a sketch in Arduino using Sublime Text 2.
Initially had trouble compiling the file, which could resolve adding the ways: *C:\WinAVR-20100110\avr\bin*, *C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin* and *C:\ WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin* to the path.

My problem now is that I can compile, but I can not upload to the board. When I tried to upload, the following message was sent:

---

"*Binary sketch size: 1094 bytes (of a 32256 byte maximum, 3.39 percent).*

*Estimated memory use: 11 bytes (of a 2048 byte maximum, 0.54 percent).*

*[Stino - Done compiling.]*

*Uploading...*

*The system cannot find the file specified.*

*[Stino - Error 1]*"

---

I am seen in the answers to similar problems that the problem is the environment variables to be placed in the path, but have not seen any case like mine, where only the compilation problem is resolved.

My OS is Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your upload command?

Comment: I am simply trying to upload by the Sublime Text arduino package menu: Arduino > Upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Arduino plugin is 1) ancient, 2) (barely) ported from a [TextMate](https://macromates.com/) `.tmBundle`, and 3) only works on OS X. All of the commands rely on programs stored in `/Applications/Arduino.app`, which you obviously don't have on your Windows system. So, instead of using this plugin, you have two options: you can run all your commands through the Windows Arduino tools, or you can uninstall your current plugin and instead install the plugin called [`Arduino-like IDE`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Arduino-like%20IDE) through Package Control. I haven't used it, but it is much more up-to-date than the old one, and is cross-platform, meaning it'll work on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm already using the plugin **Arduino-like IDE**. I tried to reinstall but the problem still there.